# Is it possible to get the (x, y) position of nodes in a `Graph`?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Given a graph...

```
RandomGraph[{20,40}]
```

[image]

...is it possible to retrieve the (x, y) coordinates at which the nodes are drawn?

`InputForm` only appears to give the `SparseArray` of data behind it:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
 {Null, SparseArray[Automatic, {20, 20}, 0, {1, {{0, 6, 11, 13, 16, 19, 25, 32, 36, 37, 40, 
     44, 49, 51, 60, 64, 66, 69, 73, 77, 80}, {{2}, {7}, {11}, {12}, {14}, {15}, {1}, {6}, 
     {8}, {10}, {19}, {11}, {14}, {6}, {8}, {14}, {9}, {10}, {17}, {2}, {4}, {7}, {11}, {12}, 
     {19}, {1}, {6}, {10}, {12}, {14}, {15}, {17}, {2}, {4}, {13}, {20}, {5}, {2}, {5}, {7}, 
     {1}, {3}, {6}, {16}, {1}, {6}, {7}, {14}, {18}, {8}, {14}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {7}, {12}, 
     {13}, {15}, {18}, {20}, {1}, {7}, {14}, {18}, {11}, {19}, {5}, {7}, {18}, {12}, {14}, 
     {15}, {17}, {2}, {6}, {16}, {20}, {8}, {14}, {19}}}, Pattern}]}]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use [`GraphEmbedding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphEmbedding.html).

`Graph` is atomic and you should not try to extract any information from it by looking at its input form.  It is not reliable, can change between versions, undocumented, etc.  Nor is the input form directly accessible with things like `Part`.

Comment: Is `GraphEmbedding` a common term in graph world? Because it is not even once mentioned in `VertexCoordinates` page, where I would start looking probably.

Comment: @Kuba The term "embedding" is pretty common as far as I know.  I think a suggestion to put it under "See Also" both for GraphLayout and VertexCoordinates would be in order (Feedback link at the bottom of each online doc page).

Comment: @Kuba `GraphEmbedding` is new in 9.0 btw.  `Graph` was introduced in 8.0 and I *think* it wasn't so straightforward to get these coordinates at that time.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, one can use `AbsoluteOptions[]` to extract the coordinates:

```
g = RandomGraph[{20, 40}];
coords = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates];
```

You can verify that `coords === GraphEmbedding[g]` gives `True`.